# Struts2 Hibernate in maven

Tags: hibernate, maven, struts2

how to integrate hibernate to struts2 in maven. i know to add hibernate dependencies to pom.xml but i dont know exactly what are the jar files needed. i tried all the jar files of hibernate resulting in 404 page not found error.
can some to tell me exactly what are the jar files needed for Struts2 hibernate in maven.an example would be appreciable.

Here is code of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-   v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>org</groupId>
  <artifactId>Strurts2Hibernate</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Strurts2Hibernate Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default-tools.jar</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>java.vendor</name>
                <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.21</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.ga</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-tree</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>


 </dependencies>

  <build>
<finalName>Strurts2Hibernate</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Web.xml

```
   <web-app>
<display-name>Struts 2 Web Application</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Struts.xml

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

  <package name="myhibernate" extends="hibernate-default">

  <action name="addStudent" method="execute" class="com.in.AddStudentAction">
     <result name="success" type="redirect">
           listStudents
     </result>
  </action>

  <action name="listStudents" method="listStudents" class="com.in.AddStudentAction">
     <result name="success">/students.jsp</result>
  </action>

 </package>

 </struts>
```

i google it says some jar conflict cant find which jar files....

Comment: It would help if you posted the exact error you encountered while deploying/running the app in your server.

Comment: You don't *have* to know the jar files needed, that's the point of Maven. Without seeing the logs it's impossible to help.

Comment: can you post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what all you have done so far, adding following entry will do most of work for you

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.x.x-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Struts2 is independent of hibernate and so its same as you add a simple hibernate dependency to your application

Sometime hibernate dependency show up some error while downloading dependencies from [Maven central repository](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/) , so in that case you need to add following entry in your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
  ...
</repositories>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Umesh see my code l post it now so that you will get full view about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing here is that Maven will handle the transitive dependencies for you.  This means that you only have to select the "top level" persistence dependency, and all of the secondary things ( the transitive dependencies ) will be pulled in by Maven for you.  A lot of developers still apply the "what are all the jars I need" logic when trying to populate their POM dependency lists.  This is unnecessary and confusing.  You'll have to figure out which dependency you actually need yourself by perusing the Hibernate / JPA docs.

In my case, I work with a project that is using JPA Annotations as it's approach to persistence.  In this case, we only need the single, following dependency in our poms.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I see that you are using hibernate 4.x, so you'll have to figure out exactly which one you are using, but I assure you that you have too many in your pom.

As another example.  Your slf4j dependencies could use the same clean up.  If you simply declare the single:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.4</version>
   </dependency>
```

Maven will obtain all the other ( transitive ) dependencies for you, such as the slf4j-api and the log4j12.